# Attaching a List to Body element using BackBone JS

Tags: backbone.js

I started learning Backbone JS.

Suppose i have a code block

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  (function($)
  {
     var ListView = Backbone.View.extend
                    (
                      {
                       el: $('body'), 
                       initialize: function()
                                  {
                                    this.render(); 
                                  },
                       render: function()
                                  {
                                    // How to attach a sample Unorder list here?
                                  }
                      }
                   );
  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

How to attach a sample unorderlist inside `render` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not understanding the exact requirement.
You can use

> .append()  method

Replace your code block with the following code snippet

```
render: function()
 {
      $(this.el).append(
                        "<ul> 
                           <li>One</li>
                           <li>Two</li>
                           <li>Three</li> 
                         </ul>"
                       );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use a template for populating a list.

HTML Template

```
<script type="text/template" id="itemViewTemplate">
  <ul>
      <% _.each(data, function(i) { %>  
          <li><%= i %></li> 
      <% }); %>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            $(this.el).append(_.template($("#itemViewTemplate").html(), {data:[0,1,2,3,4]}));
        }
    });
    var listView = new ListView();

});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AJ8xF/1/

Comment: 0.5.3 is ancient, this will fail with newer versions where `this.el` is always the raw DOM element.